# Alternatives to changing code that uses deprecated jQuery methods

Tags: jquery

Are there any alternatives when working with deprecated methods in jQuery?

Instead of changing the code, are there any compatible migration tools that make all the versioning issues go away?

Comment: The [jQuery migrate plugin](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) Might help you :)

Comment: @AmazingDreams: Your comment should be an answer.=D

Comment: ... although ideally, you'll be moving way from the deprecated methods. They are deprecated for a reason.

Comment: @Matt that is why they call it a migration plugin. It is meant for 'slow' migration to the newer jQuery versions.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is :)

The [jQuery migrate plugin](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) Might help you :)

This plugin will give support for the deprecated functions.

Note that this plugin is meant for Migration purposes only! The deprecated functions are deprecated for a reason!

Comment: I think the name of the plugin describes itself perfectly adequately.

Comment: not completely,you can mention how it can be included..anyways+1

Comment: They have a README for a reason you know... (Not sure if sarcasm though :P)

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery Migrate Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) is very helpful in upgrading from versions 1.6.4 to 1.9+. Anything below that and you may have handle the bugs on your own. When I upgraded our project from jQuery 1.4.2 to jQuery latest, I stepped up through each minor release and checked the [release notes (e.g. for 1.5.2)](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/03/31/jquery-152-released/) as I went along. One of the issues I found which won't be supported with the jQuery migrate plugin is the addition of the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method, and the new meaning of the `.attr()` method.

The main issue for me when I upgraded jQuery was changing all of my `.live()` events to `.on()`, and this plugin really helped me with that. It'll also tell you that support for the `$.browser` method has gone, though it'll offer no real solution other than using a tool like [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) and use feature-detection methods instead.

The way I went about using the script, was to download it [from here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js), and add it to your pages. Note: there are two versions of the plugin, one for development and one for production. Both try to iron out any depreciation issues, but the development on will also notify you about each of them  through the console (each starts with `JQMIGRATE`). Given that you seem to be just asking for support for depreciated methods, I'd use the production version **but** you should seriously try to replace all of your depreciated code, as modern jQuery offers some [serious performance improvements](http://jsperf.com/jquery-1-7-2-vs-jquery-1-8/40)* - most notably in jQuery 2, where support for legacy IE (<=8) has been dropped.

* *A number of tests, but jQuery 1.8/1.9 wins in all of them for me*

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have other choices than using deprecated methods, you should wrap the calls in functions so you don't have to rewrite all your code later, but the wrapper functions themselves.

```
function myRequiredFunctionality(params) {
    // ... Convert params from domain logic to what jQuery expects ...
    $.deprecatedCall( ... );
    // ...
}
```

This way your application code will only reference your `myRequiredFunctionality` function instead of the deprecated stuff, so, except the function above, your code can be left intact in case jQuery replaces the deprecated feature.

This is actually true for any third party library usage and any programming language. It is always a good idea to isolate yourself from the 3rd party stuff you use so you won't be dependent of it.